# Status Changed with Duplicates Due to Selection

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am executing a default hook called hookActionProductCancel(). The hook is executing my codes well but there is a portion that is executing more than once based on the refund/return checkboxes quantity sent.

Example:

If I have 4 checkboxes that is to be selected and I selected 3, my order will have 3 "Refund" status in order detail history. (can also be seen in order page)

```
public function hookActionProductCancel($params) 
{
    $query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select('id_order_state')
    ->from('order_state_lang')
    ->where('name = ' . "'Refund'");
    $refund_status = Db::getInstance()->getValue($query);

    $objOrder = new Order($id_order);
    $history = new OrderHistory();
    $history->id_order = (int)$objOrder->id;
    $history->id_employee = $cookie->id_employee;
    $history->changeIdOrderState($refund_status, (int)($objOrder->id));
    $history->add(true);
    $history->save();
}
```

Any guidance is truly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Because `hookActionProductCancel` executes for every cancelled product in the order.

Comment: Ah I see, precisely why I am facing this error. Is there a workaround or any other available hooks I am able to use that will return me as 1? The rest of my codes are running fine but this has caused a slight issue now.

Comment: @TheDrot So, by default, this is running in a loop? For hookActionProductCancel

Comment: Yes a loop for each cancelled product and a hook is executed. `Tools::getValue('id_order_detail')` is an array of products cancelled, so you could create a counter in your module and when the counter is the same as number of cancelled products, change your order state.

Comment: Yes, I am using Tools::getValue('id_order_detail') for other parts of my codes and using a foreach loop to access the values. Can I just ask in the code posted above, how is it running based on the number of selected checkbox? Which part of the code is triggering the number of times it is switching the status? I am lost on this part. Thank you.

Comment: @TheDrot Tools::getValue('id_order_detail') is indeed the number of cancelled products checkbox because it is returning the id_order_detail. So if I check 4 boxes, it will return 4 ids. What do I compare it with since that is the counter for cancelled product checkboxes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cancelling products from an order, controller loops through each selected product and executes `actionProductCancel` hook.

`Tools::getValue('id_order_detail')` will be an array of each order detail id that will get cancelled.

Knowing that you can use a combination of the hook, count of order detail ids in array and a counter in the module.

Your main module class could contain code like this:

```
public static $cancelledProductCount = 0;

public function hookActionProductCancel($params) 
{
    self::$cancelledProductCount++;

    if (self::$cancelledProductCount == count(Tools::getValue('id_order_detail'))) {
        $query = new DbQuery();
        $query->select('id_order_state')
              ->from('order_state_lang')
              ->where('name = ' . "'Refund'");
        $refund_status = Db::getInstance()->getValue($query);

        $objOrder = new Order($id_order);
        $history = new OrderHistory();
        $history->id_order = (int)$objOrder->id;
        $history->id_employee = $cookie->id_employee;
        $history->changeIdOrderState($refund_status, (int)($objOrder->id));
        $history->add(true);
        $history->save();
    }
}
```

So every time a cancel product hook executes you increase counter by one and compare with the count of cancelled items. If they are the same, you know it's the last time the hook will execute so change the order state.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try soon! Much appreciated!

Comment: Hello @TheDrot, Thank you so much for the suggestion, it is working perfectly. There is a missing ) in the if statement, but you rock! Solution is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @Enthu Glad it's working. And you're right it was missing ).